# How can I setup fish shell prompt to be in a different color?

Tags: fish

I've seen a screenshot of zsh configured to have prompt with a different color and background, and it looks like a very usable tweak:

[image]

Comment: See if [this](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#set_color) is of any help.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it only changes the color for the whole terminal, not the prompt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sammyg was correct that [`set_color`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#set_color) is what you're looking for. The trick is that a single call to `set_color` doesn't color a specified block of text, but sets the color that all subsequent text will be printed. The `-b` flag sets the background color. Here's a simple function which will give you a similar effect to that `zsh` prompt (put it in your `fish/functions` directory):

```
function fish_prompt
    set -l textcol  white
    set -l bgcol    blue
    set -l arrowcol green
    set_color $textcol -b $bgcol
    echo -n " "(basename $PWD)" "
    set_color $arrowcol -b normal
    echo -n "⮀ "
end
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly reset the colors after drawing the prompt, `fish` will do that automatically.